# Displaying iAd Banner above Tab Bar in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, iad

So I have implemented iAd into my app, imported the framework and imported it into my View Controller and added the delegate and all that. I do see it when I run my app, however, I have a tab bar (I am not using a tab bar controller if that matters) and I want to have the iAd above the tab bar, as currently I am getting it below the tab bar and feel this isn't good for the user experience, and also on Apple's documentation is mentions to put it directly above a tab bar (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/iAdRichMediaAds.html). I have been playing around with it, but haven't gotten anything to work, and was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on my code posted below. Thanks.

```
 var bannerView: ADBannerView!
 @IBOutlet weak var tabBar: UITabBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
        bannerView = ADBannerView(frame: CGRectZero)
        bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height - bannerView.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, bannerView.frame.size.height)
        bannerView.alpha = 0.0
        bannerView.delegate = self
        self.view!.addSubview(bannerView)

    func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        print("bannerViewDidLoadAd")
        bannerView.hidden = false
    }

    func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {banner.alpha = 1.0})
        UIView.commitAnimations()
        bannerView.hidden = true
    }

    func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

first of all, this line makes no sense

```
bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height - bannerView.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, bannerView.frame.size.height)
```

you are setting "bannerView.frame" using properties of "bannerView.frame" you just made with "CGRectZero" ????

Any way before do anything just read this :
https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a

Comment: This is a totally unproductive answer. I came across this question trying to place a view right above the tab bar, so a real answer *could* have been helpful...